# Probability about finding a pattern

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a problem in Probability, I am a bit confused how to resolve this.

A network employee is observing a set of 10 wireless access points. At any given time, an access point can be in one of the following three states: (on), stand-by (sb) or error (err). We can consider that all states are independent.
a)  How many possible state patterns are possible for these 10 access points (e.g. 1st  point on, 2nd point err, 3rd point on, 4th point sb, …10th)?

b)  What is the probability that the employee will find the 10 access points in this configuration (but not only in this order): any 3 access points in the ‘on’ state, any 5 in the ‘sb’ state and any 2 in the ‘err’ state?

What I have tried for a), but I am not sure.
Since it is a permutational problem (order matters) I figured I shall use the formula P(n,r) = n! / (n-r)! , so P(10,3)= 10!/7! = 720 possible patterns

About b) I am confused how to solve it given that is another permutational problem where order matters, but combining this with the Law of total probability possibly?

Thank you very much for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (b) depends on whether I have interpreted the answer to (a) correctly.

As I see it, you have 10 different access points, each of which has 3 possible states.

So for part (a) answer $= 3^{(10)}.$

Part (b) can be simplified by letting

$A = \frac{1}{3^{(10)}} =$ chance of any one situation occuring.

Then the answer to part (b) is $A \times $ the # of different situations.

The # of different situations is $S = \binom{10}{5} \times \binom{5}{3}.$

So the answer to part (b) is $A \times S.$

Please leave a comment/question directly below this answer, if any questions.

I will automatically be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

$10$ access points with $3$ possible states.

(a) your answer wound be $3(10) = 30$.

(b) can be simplified by letting

$A=\frac 1 {3^{10}} =$ chance of any one situation occurring. $A$ times the number of situations $S=\frac{10}5\times\frac 5 3$.

(b) is $A\times S$.